# Call python co-routine from javascript in PyQt5

Tags: javascript, python, asynchronous, pyqt

I have a very complex loop, that depends on things like network and a peripheral, and I'd like to make it asynchronous.

```
def Foo(QObject):
    @pyqtSlot(int)
    def complexloop(self):
        do_something_complex

    @pyqtSlot(int, result=int)
    def something_simple(self):
        return "something easy"
```

This class is added to a webkit window, in PyQt5, like this:

```
class Window(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super(Window, self).__init__()
    self.view = QWebView(self)

    self.foo = Foo(self)
    self.view.page().mainFrame().addToJavaScriptWindowObject("foo", self.foo)
```

This way, in JavaScript, I can call `foo.complexloop()` to start the process.

The problem is that when I do that, the whole browser freezes until the loop is completed. I need a way to run this loop in background.

I've tried to define `complexloop` with `async def`, but I can't find any documentation on how to call it from JavaScript then.

I tried to wrap the call into something like:

```
def call_loop(self):
    try:
        self.complex_loop.send(None)
    except StopIteration:
        pass
```

But that doesn't help, since the call to `foo.call_loop()` will block the window.

Comment: You can call in non-blocking mode, i.e. `asyncio.ensure_future(foo.complexloop())`

Comment: `ensure_future` still blocks the window

Comment: Which part of you code is blocking the window, `javascript` or `python`? Sorry I'm not familiar with PyQt.

Comment: The javascript call will only finish once the python function returns.

Comment: `asyncio.ensure_future` will always return immediately.

Comment: If I call `asyncio.ensure_future(self.complexloop())` it doesn't do anything. If I call `asyncio.ensure_future(self.complexloop.send(None))`, it blocks.

Comment: You have to run the event loop in a python thread. In addition, don't call `send()` manually on coroutines. In thread1, run `loop.run_forever()`, in `call_loop()` do `loop.call_soon_threadsafe(loop.create_task, foo.complexloop())`.